# 'moment' library not working in StackBlitz project

Tags: angular

I am having problem to get moment library working with a basic app. It does not compile complaining about `Error in src/app/app.component.ts (17:23)`. Here is StackBlitz of an [app]:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-awrzvp?file=src/app/app.component.ts
I am using Angular version 14.0.5.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
import * as moment from 'moment'
```

To

```
const moment = require('moment')
```

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/typescript/

Comment: Thank you. However if I do that change then it works in StackBlitz but stopped working in Visual Studio Code - underlying with red colour the word `moment` after `import` word                   displaying an error `Module '"C:/Angular/GitHub/moment-example/node_modules/moment/ts3.1-typings/moment"' can only be default-imported using the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag`

2 import moment from 'moment';

Comment: My Angular typescript is of version 4.7.4. Is it type script 1.x or 2.x

Comment: 4.7.4 should be 4.x. Did the require not work?

Comment: No. It works as as you first suggested  using `import moment from 'moment';` and specifying compiler option `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true`. I don't understand why it works but it does